# Range Slider for Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I was wondering if there was a way to create a range slider for an OS X app in Cocoa.  Basically it's just a regular slider with two buttons instead of one, so you can set a range (for a graph for example).  I've seen a lot of custom range sliders for iOS (such as http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/rangeslider), but none for OS X.

The closest thing I could find was SMDoubleSlider, which doesn't seem to work at all in XCode 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible, almost anything is, but you would have to do all the drawing and handling of the slider movement yourself.

I'm not sure what you mean about SMDoubleSlider not working in Xcode 4 -- I tried it out, and it worked fine for me.  I didn't try the IB plugin stuff, I just imported the 4 files (SMDoubleSlider .h and .m and the slider cell files as well) and alloc init'ed it to create one and add it to my view.  I was able to get and set the values of the hi and lo sliders.
If you're going to use it, just make sure you abide by the copyright restrictions, it is open source, but not public domain.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the SMDoubleSlider to work.  I thought I would need a custom IB Object, but I just used an NSView and subclassed it as SMDoubleSlider and was able to get everything working.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: I just learned the hard way that SMDoubleSlider uses private APIs that will not pass App Review. Don't use this class if you intend to distribute your app through the Mac App Store.